# Library supported in Python but not supported in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

I am trying to run tornado web server on google app engine. I can successfully import tornado library from python console or when directly launching .py file but when I try to launch using:

```
python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py tutorial/
```

it ends with

```
ImportError: No module named tornado
```

I read in similar topic that I should include lines like

```
libraries:
  - name: tornado
    version: "latest"
```

to my app.yaml file but then it ends with

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "tornado" is not supported
```

how do I make libraries supported?

Comment: Why do you want to install Tornado on GAE? What do you think it will do?

Comment: I want GAE to upload my app to a hosting. Would you suggest a better option for hosting? What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. I don't think you know what GAE is: it *is* a hosting environment. You don't need Tornado, or any other server software, it's all built in. You should really read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are a [list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) of libraries which you can import by using app.yaml. Tornado is not included in this list, so you need to add this library into your project's folder, so it will be deployed with your app.

You can try to use `pip install tornado --target=/project/folder` but you will get some junk folders as well.